# Ruby support in vim

Tags: ruby, vim

If I want to work with Ruby in Vim, how can I add Ruby support to it?

Comment: What do you mean by "Ruby support"?

Comment: Install this - http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1567 . There are other scripts out there, just google around and see which one you like

Comment: Same question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3794895/installing-vim-with-ruby-support-ruby

Comment: @Dogbert. Working with `ruby` in `vim`, and saving the file directly as `.rb`

Comment: assuming you're looking for ruby syntax highlight, it should be available in vim (at least any recent version). Use `:setf ruby` to mark the current buffer as a ruby file. If you want code completion, use `Ctrl-x Ctrl-o`.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, you would need a Vim version that is compiled with Ruby support enabled. You achieve this with:

```
./configure <the rest of your options> --enable-rubyinterp
```

on a Linux system, for example.

The next steps would be installing the plugins of your choice, you probably want NERDTree, snipMate, vim-ruby-debugger....

There are a lot of plugins to make your life easier, but there is always the option to run arbitrary shell commands from within Vim, no extra plugin needed:

```
!ruby /path/to/script.rb
```

This will execute script.rb and print the shell output directly in Vim itself.

Answer (score 1):

I would visit https://github.com/ and put "ruby vim" into search box. You should find plenty interesting add-ons for vim this way.