# Vim Command-T plugin error: could not load the C extension

Tags: ruby, vim, plugins

I'm trying to install the Command-T plugin.

I compiled vim following the instructions in this comment: [Installing vim with ruby support (+ruby)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3794895/installing-vim-with-ruby-support-ruby/3851435#3851435)

So now there's the +ruby flag, but still when I try to use the plugin I get this error:

```
command-t.vim could not load the C extension
Please see INSTALLATION and TROUBLE-SHOOTING in the help              
For more information type:    :help command-t
```

I have ruby on my system:

```
> ruby -v
> ruby 1.8.7 (2011-06-30 patchlevel 352) [x86_64-linux]
```

suggestions?

Comment: You might want to have a look at [ctrlp.vim](https://github.com/kien/ctrlp.vim) which is basically the same as [Command-T](https://github.com/wincent/Command-T) but written in pure Vimscript. This means it neither requires Ruby support enabled in Vim nor does it require the compilation of some Ruby extension implemented in C.

Comment: Ctrl+P is nice as well, but it doesn't handle huge projects as good as Command+T

Answer (score 107):

Go to plugin dir and run the following command:

```
rake make
```

It compiles the plugin extension you need.

Comment: @CoreyRothwell make that 2 days. Jeez, sometimes I need to google before going through documentation over and over again.

Comment: RVM users make sure you're using the exact ruby version that Vim says it's using in the error message

Answer (score 33):

I ran into the same error but after reading the manual a bit more thorough I found the following helpful.

Tagged from the INSTALLATION section in https://github.com/wincent/Command-T

> The C extension must then be built, which can be done from the shell. If you
> use a typical |'runtimepath'| then the files were installed inside ~/.vim and
> you can build the extension with:

```sh
cd ~/.vim/ruby/command-t/ext/command-t
ruby extconf.rb
make
```

Comment: The comment above suggesting `rake make` didn't work for me. I installed CommandT with vundle and there is no Makefile. To add to this answer, I had to go to
~/.vim/bundle/Command-T/ruby/command-t
and run the commands suggested here. For my system this also involved installing the ruby-dev package. Thanks peralmq!

Comment: Now the correct directory for extconf.rb is: "<YourRepoDir>/command-t/ruby/command-t/ext/command-t/". If it changes again, you can search for 'extconf.rb' at https://github.com/wincent/command-t/find/master.

Comment: Run ruby command "ruby extconf.rb" using the same ruby version that vim is using. This should not be by using rvm or other ruby. It should be the ruby that is installed on your system.

Answer (score 4):

**You must perform the build using the same version of Ruby that Vim itself is linked against.**

Are you using RVM or rbenv?  Personally, I was using rbenv and MacVim.  I had this error because I was trying use ruby 1.8.7 patch **352**.  I switched back to 1.8.7 patch **249** using `rbenv shell system` *before* running `ruby extconf.rb` and `make`, then everything worked fine.

Afterwards, you can revert your shell back using `rbenv shell --unset`.

Answer (score 2):

On debian squeeze I also had to install the json library for ruby with `apt-get install libjson-ruby1.8`

Answer (score 1):

Command-T requires a compiled component.   The error message suggests you haven't followed the installation instructions for the plugin completely.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the installation instructions on: https://github.com/wincent/Command-T
Search on that page for the header "INSTALLATION".  You most likely did not follow the instructions from this official README.  If you are using RVM make sure to use the system ruby.  This is all notated in the docs.

Answer (score 1):

If you are sure you follow the instruction on [the github project](https://github.com/wincent/Command-T),maybe you need to restart vim and the terminal. I came across the same problem and when I restarted Vim, it finally worked!

Answer (score 1):

I got similar error and tried `rake make` as suggested in one of the answers, which also runs `ruby extconf.rb`, I got following error

```
─$ rake make
/usr/bin/ruby2.3 extconf.rb
mkmf.rb can't find header files for ruby at /usr/lib/ruby/include/ruby.h
rake aborted!
Command failed with status (1): [/usr/bin/ruby2.3 extconf.rb...]
/home/shreedhan/.vim/bundle/command-t/Rakefile:84:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
/home/shreedhan/.vim/bundle/command-t/Rakefile:83:in `chdir'
/home/shreedhan/.vim/bundle/command-t/Rakefile:83:in `block in <top (required)>'
Tasks: TOP => make
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

You need to install `ruby-devel` or `ruby-dev` based on whether you have `yum` or `apt` on your distro.

```
yum install ruby-devel
```

or

```
$ apt install ruby-dev
```

Answer (score 0):

Eventually, after some trial and error, I found this command in the command-t FAQ, which deals with a Mac OS issue.  I'm running "High Sierra 10.13.4":

ARCHFLAGS=-Wno-error=unused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future ruby extconf.rb

This seemed to generate a Makefile that ran the compile successfully.  I tried a lot of stuff though, and this solution feels a little cargo-culty.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by doing the following steps:

1. find your **ruby** folder in your **~/.vim**, since mine could not be found in ~/.vim/ruby
2. `find . -name "extconf.rb"`- find the **extconf.rb** file, which may be located in a **command-t** folder
3. `ruby extconf.rb`
4. `make`
5. re-open vim

It may be also useful to read the documentation inside vim (`:help command-t`)