# Vim Command-T in Ubuntu: command-t.vim could not load the C extension

Tags: vim

I am trying to learn vim for my job. I am very new to vim so please go easy on me. I installed `command-t` plugin using `vundle`. But when I press `leader + t` I get following errors:

> command-t.vim could not load the C extension
>   Please see INSTALLATION and TROUBLE-SHOOTING in the help
>   Vim Ruby version: 1.9.3-p484
>   Expected version: 2.2.2-p95

Below are details about my system:

- OS: Ubuntu 14 running on Vagrant
- installed Ruby 2.2.2 and ruby-1.9.3-p484 using Rvm.
- gcc version 4.8.4 (Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04)

Ruby 2.2.2 is my default version for my project. Do I need to upgrade Vim Ruby to 2.2.2. If yes then how can I upgrade Vim Ruby in Ubuntu.

I already read couple of solution on Stackoverflow and run `rake make` from plugin folder. But still I am getting the same error.

## Update

Below are result from `rake make` command

```
➜  command-t git:(master) rake make
/home/vagrant/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/bin/ruby extconf.rb
checking for float.h... yes
checking for ruby.h... yes
checking for stdlib.h... yes
checking for string.h... yes
checking for fcntl.h... yes
checking for stdint.h... yes
checking for sys/errno.h... yes
checking for sys/socket.h... yes
checking for ruby/st.h... yes
checking for st.h... yes
checking for pthread_create() in -lpthread... yes
creating Makefile
compiling watchman.c 
compiling ext.c
compiling match.c
compiling matcher.c
linking shared-object ext.so
```

Answer (score 2):

The [README](https://github.com/wincent/command-t/blob/7364a410bc4f0d7febc183678cd565066dfd1e73/doc/command-t.txt#L309) mentions that the extension can be built by:

```
cd ~/.vim/bundle/command-t/ruby/command-t/ext/command-t
ruby extconf.rb
make
```

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7923002/vim-command-t-plugin-error-could-not-load-the-c-extension), you need must build against the same version as used by Vim.

I think the easiest solution will be rebuilding the plugin with ruby-1.9.3-p484. Prepend the path to this installation to your $PATH, check the version with `ruby -v` and reinstall the plugin.