# Vim command-t plugin, Mac OS Sierra 10.12.6: could not load C extension

Tags: ruby, vim, homebrew

I just updated my OS X to Sierra 10.12.6. When I open vim and try to use command-t I am getting the following error:

```
command-t.vim could not load the C extension.
Please see INSTALLATION and TROUBLE-SHOOTING in the help.
Vim Ruby version: 2.5.0-p0
Expected version: 2.4.1-p111
For more information type:    :help command-t
```

My current state of the world happened after the following: 
 1. `brew uninstall ruby vim` => `brew install ruby vim`

I've tried implementing advice from the following stackoverflow + github issues:

- [Vim Command-T plugin error: could not load the C extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7923002/vim-command-t-plugin-error-could-not-load-the-c-extension)
- https://github.com/wincent/command-t/issues/214
- https://github.com/wincent/command-t/issues/196
- https://github.com/wincent/command-t/issues/275
- https://github.com/wincent/command-t/issues/119
- https://github.com/wincent/command-t/issues/271
- https://github.com/wincent/command-t/issues/242
- https://askubuntu.com/questions/49469/command-t-vim-could-not-load-c-extension
- https://wincent.com/forums/command-t/topics/427

And of course, the command-t documentation: (https://github.com/wincent/command-t/blob/master/doc/command-t.txt). Unfortunately, most of these examples are old and not relevant to the most recent MacOS, Ruby, or Vim versions. The path to my `ruby extconf.rb` is also slightly different than the examples...

Path to where `extconf.rb` lives in the examples:

```
cd ~/.vim/bundle/command-t/ruby/command-t
```

Path on my computer:

```
cd ~/.vim/bundle/command-t/ruby/command-t/ext/command-t
```

Any advice is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Maybe you should downgrade Ruby to 2.4 version and reinstall Vim after?

Comment: Use the plugin's issue tracker.

Answer (score 2):

Have you build the C-extension? If not, run

`ruby extconf.rb && make`

in the directory

`~/.vim/bundle/command-t/ruby/command-t/ext/command-t`

Afterwards, `command-t` should work. If not, you could post the output of `make` here.