# Installing Vim with the Ruby Interpreter

Tags: ruby, vim

I am trying to install vim with the ruby interpreter. Following this [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3794895/installing-vim-with-ruby-support-ruby) and documentation, I completed the following steps.

On a Linux 64-bit OS:

```
hg clone https://vim.googlecode.com/hg/ vim
cd vim
./configure --enable-rubyinterp=yes
make
sudo make install
```

However, I still receive:

```
vim --version | grep ruby
-python3 +quickfix +reltime -rightleft -ruby +scrollbind +signs +smartindent
```

I do have a system ruby installed (rvm not yet installed):

```
ruby -v
ruby 1.8.7 (2010-08-16 patchlevel 302) [x86_64-linux]
```

My Google foo and research has hit a wall, any suggestions about how I figure out what I am doing incorrectly?

Comment: Do you have Ruby development libraries installed? What does configure print about Ruby? Is there anything about ruby in config.log? What distribution?

Comment: @themel I didn't have Ruby development files installed. I installed ruby1.8-dev and compiled again with success. Thank you!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to install ruby header files first. Like this:

```
sudo apt-get install ruby-dev
./configure --enable-rubyinterp
```

Comment: Turns out that I was missing the development packages for Ruby. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this [gist](https://gist.github.com/1240704). I wrote it and use it all the time. It works fine. Probably you should change your configure command to something like:

```
./configure --enable-rubyinterp
```

By the way, the gist contains the reference to the set of library you need to compile vim with ruby on an debian-like distro.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the link! Those are helpful setup instructions.