# Using vim to generate tables of integer-based random numbers?

Tags: ruby, vim

There are times when I want to generate random numbers (in a free space-delimited format), but I want to be able to specify the number of rows and columns.

I see some motivation from here to generate a single instance of a random number (derived from using ruby):
http://mo.morsi.org/blog/node/299

" generate random number at end of current line

```
function! s:Rand(max)
y a         
redir @b    
ruby << EOF
  rmax = VIM::evaluate("a:max")
  rmax = nil if rmax == ""
  printf rand(rmax).to_s
EOF
redir END 
let @a = strpart(@a, 0, strlen(@a) - 1)
let @b = strpart(@b, 1, strlen(@b) - 1)
let @c = @a . @b
.s/.*/\=@c/g
endfunction
```

How could we extend this trivially to such a way that I can type

:Rand(6,6)

and generate a table beginning at my cursor position?

For users unaware, vim needs +ruby support: [Installing vim with ruby support (+ruby)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3794895/installing-vim-with-ruby-support-ruby)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cycle through x and y coordinates and provide max of random numbers.

```
function! Rand(max)
   redir @b
ruby << EOF
  rmax = VIM::evaluate("a:max")
  rmax = nil if rmax == ""
  printf rand(rmax).to_s
EOF
   redir END
   let @a = strpart(@a, 0, strlen(@a) - 1)
   let @b = strpart(@b, 1, strlen(@b) - 1)
   let @c = @a . @b
   return @c
endfunction

fun! RandTable(...)
   for y in range(a:2)
      for x in range(a:1)
         if a:0 > 2
            let rand = Rand(a:3)
         else
            let rand = Rand(10)
         end
         exe "norm i" . rand . "  "
      endfor
      exe "norm Xi\<cr>"
   endfor
endfun

command! -nargs=* Rand call RandTable(<f-args>)
```

now you can use `:Rand 6 6` or `:Rand 6 6 6` where the third argument specifies max of random number.

Answer (score 4):

I'm usually lazy and just do something like

```
od -iAn -w 12 /dev/urandom | head -n 30
```

This would generate lines with 3 columns of random ints. Of course you can slap a command onto it, as ever:

```
fun! RTable(r,c)
    exec 'r!od -iAn -w' . (4*a:c) . ' /dev/urandom | head -n ' . a:r
endf
command! -nargs=+ RTable call RTable(<f-args>)
```

Now you can, at leisure

```
RTable 5 5
RTable 1 500
```

etc.

Comment: This is pretty effective, especially without the need for +ruby support, too bad I can't have multiple accepted answers!